# Помогите решить задачу на С++

Tags: c++, visual-c++

Дана последовательность из n слов. Для каждого элемента определить, сколько раз это слово встречалось в этой последовательности раньше ( на позициях с меньшим индексом). С++. Это в теме множества, словари еще не учили, проблема в том, что я не понимаю как с помощью контейнера multiset\set ввести семь слов?

```
int n;
cin >> n;
multiset <string> a;
for (int i = 0; i <= n; i++) { 
    string s; 
    getline(cin, s); 
    a.insert(s); }
for (auto s : a) { cout << s << endl; }
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Если я Вас правильно понял, то это делается вот так:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <set>

using namespace std;

int main() { 
  int n;
  cin>>n;
  string s[n];
  int ans[n];
  multiset<string> st;
  for(int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    cin>>s[i];
    ans[i] = st.count(s[i]);
    st.insert(s[i]);
  }

  for(int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    cout<<s[i]<<": "<<ans[i]<<'\n';
  }
  return 0;
}
```

С помощью функции `insert` Вы добавляете элемент в `multiset`. А с помощью `count`, можно посчитать количество вхождений определенной строки в Вашем `multiset`

Comment: а, блин, вот я глупенький) можно же тип контейнера стринг поставить и работать с контейнером в котором слова?

Comment: спасибо большое

Comment: а можно устроить ввод через пробел : 7 a b c d e t g? А не через ентер

Comment: Да. Нужно вместо `getline` использовать просто `cin`, как я указал в своем коде. Ведь `getline` считывает всю строку, пока Вы не нажмете `enter`. А `cin` считывает до пробела. 

Кстати, зачем Вы изменили свой вопрос и вставили туда код? И там есть маленькая ошибка - Ваш первый цикл сделает `n + 1` итераций вместо `n`.